# PHP - Returning datetime of NULL throws error

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format, symfony-3.4

I am extracting some data from a db, but my DateTime field is causing issues.

If I set the DateTime field, it returns fine, but when I set it to NULL, it always throws an error.

My first code:

```
$results = $this->getMyRepository()->findAll();

$rows = [];

$rows[] = array(
    "id",
    "created"
);

foreach ($results as $row) {
    $rows[] = [
        $row->getId(),
        $row->getCreated(new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'),
    ];
}
return $rows;
}
```

Error:

> Call member function format on null

My second changes the `$row->getCreated()` assignment:

```
$row->getCreated() ?? new \DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

This gives:

```
> Coalesce operator is available in PHP 7 only.
```

When I execute php -v it says PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 on Symfony 3.4. and other syntax errors with this code.

Can someone help with synatax or tell me how to make datetime work on NULL?

Comment: PHP CLI !== php for your project

Comment: Is this a PHP error or a warning from your IDE? "Coalesce operator is availbale in PHP 7 only."

Comment: It's a warning. @Funfare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PHP 7 runs on you machine you could do it like this:

```php
$row->getCreated() ?? (new \DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

So with an extra `(` before new \DateTime

If you have to do it with lower PHP version

```php
$createdAt = $row->getCreatedAt();
if (!$createdAt) {
    $now = new DateTime('now');
    $createdAt = $now->format('Y-m-d');
}

$rows[] = [
    $row->getId(),
   $createdAt,
];
```